# 「～れば」 form for 「です」

Tags: verbs, conjugations

A question came up recently that made me wonder how this form is for the verb です.

I know that です has a ～たら form that is conjugated as だったら。But, does it have a ～れば form? Is it でれば？ (I don't think so because that's more likely 出れば。) Is it だれば？ Or is it であれば？ (from である rather than です）

If it is であれば, why is that so?

I know that once I knew this but I seem to have forgotten. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **is** 〜であれば.  This is because です is really just a contraction of であります。 So you simply take the 〜れば form of あります, which is あれば.

Similarly, the だったら you mentioned is also just a contraction of であったら, and you can see あったら is just the 〜たら form of あります.

Comment: Thanks for that. I knew I knew it was であれば but once I forgot why, I started questioning it and got confused.

Comment: Don't forget なら.